# Rails parse HTTPparty json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm making request like this:

```
response = HTTParty.get("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/#{ id }.json")
```

And my `response.body` does look like this:

```
[{"id"=>44747277, "title"=>"ALPINIST feat. Chris O'Hara of PATSY O'HARA", ...}]
```

When I'm trying response.body["id"] it returns `id`, so, how I can handle this json correctly?

Comment: you see, that there is an array around the hash you're looking for? try `body[0]['id']`

Comment: @MarianTheisen, I don't think that would have anything to do with the return value being `id`. Shouldn't `response.body['id']` return an error?

Comment: `response.body[0]` returns `[`

Comment: @Nikita, you may want to make a minor (but material) revision to the question to show the array as appearing within double quotes, such that it's actually a _string_. What `response.body` is really returning is `"[{"id"=>44747277, "title"=>"ALPINIST feat. Chris O'Hara of PATSY O'HARA", ...}]"'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`response` is an `HTTParty::Response` object. `response.body` returns the body in a string format. To get it as an array, run the HTTParty [`parsed_response`](http://rdoc.info/github/jnunemaker/httparty/HTTParty/Response) method on your object. That will provide an array that you can operate on in the fashion depicted in the question.

```
response.parsed_response[0]['id'] #=> 44747277
```

Comment: Why do we need `parsed_response`?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is returning an array, thus to get the first element's `id` you should do something like:

```
response[0]['id']
```